# Scrape multiple links from a json file

Tags: python, json, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape multiple links that i have previously scraped and saved in a json file.

this works so far but i dont want to just scrape that one url but all from my json file.

```py
import scrapy
import json

class RatingSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "rating"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.darkpattern.games/game/3478/0/ragnarok-m-eternal-love-rom-.html'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
            
    def parse(self, response):
        for rating in response.css('div.score_box'):
            yield {
                'reported': rating.css('div.score_heading *::text').extract()
                
            }
```

the json file looks like this

```json
[
  {
    "title": [
      "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t",
      "Ragnarok M: Eternal Love(ROM)",
      "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t",
      "\t\t\t\t\t\t",
      "The classic adventure returns",
      "\n\t\t\t\t\t"
    ],
    "link": [
      "/game/3478/0/ragnarok-m-eternal-love-rom-.html"
    ],
    "rating": [
      "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t",
      "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t",
      "-4.68",
      "\n\t\t\t\t\t"
    ]
  }
]
```

any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in your example where you are reading from your json file. You would need to do something like this:

```
with open("your json file", "r") as f:
    jsonlist = json.load(f)

for i in range(len(jsonlist)):
    url = jsonlist[i]["link"][0]
do something with url - run request or store in list, etc. Also, Your sample json contains a relative url so I assume the rest of the file is the same and the base url is https://www.darkpattern.games so you would need to concatenate the base url - https://www.darkpattern.games - and the relative urls prior to running the requests.
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try

Comment: How do i concatenate the absolute link with the relative from the jsons?